# Java: Oracle XMLType + JDBC

Tags: java, xml, oracle, jdbc

How can I get oracle XMLElement to JDBC?

```
java.sql.Statement st = connection.createStatement(); // works
oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet rs = st.execute("SELECT XMLElement("name") FROM dual");
rs.getString(1); // returns null, why?
oracle.sql.OPAQUE = (OPAQUE) rs.getObject(1); // this works, but wtf is OPAQUE ?
```

Basically, I want to read String like `<name> </name>` or whatever XML formatted output. But I always fail to cast output to anything reasonable. Only weird oracle.sql.OPAQUE works, but I totally dont know what to do with that. Even `toString()` is not overriden!

Any ideas? How to read Oracle's (I am using Oracle 10.0.2) XMLElement (XMLType) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't. 
Oracle's JDBC driver does not support the JDBC XML type properly.

The only thing you can do, is to convert the XML as part of the query:

```
SELECT to_clob(XMLElement("name")) from dual
```

Then you can retrieve the XML using getString()

alternatively you can also use `XMLElement("name").getClobVal()`, but again this is part of your query and it can be accessed as a String from within your Java class

Comment: on SELECT to_clob(XMLElement("name")) from dual I keep getting ORA-1652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace temp

Comment: Must be something with your installation. It works fine for me (11.1.0.6). Did you try the getClobVal() version?

Comment: No, what instance should I use ?

Comment: Simply replace *to_clob(XMLElement("name"))* with *XMLElement("name").getClobVal()*

Comment: yep that worked! thank you so much ... by the way, I've never seen such terrible Java API as this, directly from Oracle ...

Comment: In version 11.2.0.2 of the oracle drivers you can use JDBC4.0 calls directly without casting. (Section 2.1.1.21 : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10881/chapter1_2.htm) Took them long enough.

Comment: @SpencerKormos Do you have any snippet for retrieving sys.xmltype as SQLXML.

Comment: @ramu nope, sorry. Haven't even used Oracle since I commented on this. Not sure when I last used XML either, actually.

Answer (score 1):

> ORA-1652: unable to extend temp segment by 128 in tablespace temp is a
>   totally different error, nothing to be with XMLElement.

It is just that you hava to set your temp file to auto resize or give it a bigger size:

```
 ALTER TABLESPACE TEMP ADD TEMPFILE '/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/oradata/oracle/temp01.dbf' SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON

ALTER DATABASE TEMPFILE '/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/db_1/oradata/oracle/temp01.dbf' RESIZE 200M
```

Comment: How does this relate to the question?